# Starting a new web application project with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee-8

I am using the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA. My first project went fine. I was able to create a simple hello world with some parameters. Now, I have decided to create a new project to test JAX-RS and some JSPs. Everything runs fine on my TomEE server.

Though, the problem I am currently facing is really weird. `request.getParameter()` is no longer recognized and similar elements. I have compared both of the old project and new project, and discovered that that new project is missing libs folder with the `javax*` files in it.

I do not know why IntelliJ no longer generates the libs files into the new projects. I would appreciate it if someone could share any helpful information.

Comment: Do you use any build tool (Maven, Gradle)? Please check that "Set library later" option isn't selected for chosen frameworks during project creation.

Comment: I steered away from this building systems because I have a bad experience with them in the past in regards to J2EE, and I am trying to learn Spring MVC. That is what I liked about IntelliJ. What bugs me is that the project included the needed libraries on the first one. I simply start a new project after installing the IDE, then selected Web Application and confirmed.

Comment: I guess you need to add "WebServices" as well, so IDE will add javax* libraries.

Comment: Sadly, it does not. It adds the javax annotation lib but that is about it for javax* libraries.

Comment: What javax* library do you need?